# Traveling with 2 passports in case of Morocco

Tags: dual-nationality, morocco, moroccan-citizens

I'm a dual national with a Moroccan passport and basically I want to ask, in the specific case of Morocco, whether it was possible to enter and exit Morocco with the Moroccan passport if I have an other nationality. I asked the question several times but I was forwarded to irrelevant and unsatisfying answers, so I'm attempting to re-ask the question.

Morocco allows dual nationality and I was planning to travel as follows.

Flight from the EU to Morocco

Check-in: Moroccan passport (so that I can show that I have a right to go to the destination country)

Exiting the EU :(no immigration for EEA nationals, just electronic counters and customs): EU passport or ID to scan (in order to prove that I've been legally in the place I'd be departing from)

Return flight from Morocco to the EU

Check-in: Italian passport, so that I can show that I have the right to go to the EU

Moroccan immigration: Moroccan passport+the other EU passport in case they ask me, so I can show that I've been there legally as a citizen and the right to go to the destination country.

Is there a flaw on this scheme? Is there something specific to Morocco, since most of Moroccan dual nationals just use their EU passport+the "Carte nationale"?

I'm asking about Morocco specifically, and please do not link me other answers on "how to travel with 2 passports" because I'm asking specifically about THIS CASE.

Comment: “THIS CASE” is not any different from other cases.

Comment: @Aganju Not necessarily. Morocco may be a different case. Just because Moroccan law (presumably) says it's OK to have another citizenship doesn't mean that, in practice, Moroccan authorities don't pick out or discriminate against Moroccan citizens who also hold another citizenship. I think that's what the question is asking.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Most dual national Moroccans do travel with the better passports along with the Moroccan national ID and they pass pretty easily. I'd want to use my Moroccan passport instead because that what's more logic, I need space in my EU passport. Many Moroccans do that because they lack a sense of transparency for themselves. I don't give out my irrelevant data (like the other nationality) easily.

Comment: @abdul, please stay respectful and do not insult people who point out what they see as a simple truth. You can ignore their remarks as well.

Comment: I agree there is nothing different here about Morocco. But in case of doubt, it's better to ask and verify than do something wrong :)

Comment: @meego I know that by logic should be this way but my father, which happens to be stubborn, fearmongers me about this. He says that Moroccan immigration could ask me an Italian visa although I have an Italian passport

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did the same trip from Paris to Rabat and back.

I passed Moroccan border control with my Moroccan passport both in and out.
When leaving the country, I recommend giving the Moroccan passport and your Italian ID (not passport, since well the border agent can stamp that instead and you say you need space in it).

Edit: I am a EU-Morocco dual citizen for clarity.

Comment: Mmm ok. But what did you check in with at departure? Moroccan passport? Thanks for the answer

Comment: I checked in with Moroccan Passport and EU ID card (check-in agents also check that you have the right to enter our destination).

Comment: Did Moroccan immigration ask you for a VISA or they simply stamp your passport?

Comment: They just stamped. You have no reason to worry, they will not ask for  a visa when you have the nationality of the country you're going to. they also have tools to know if a visa is needed or not even f you're not going directly to your country of nationality. one of them open to the public is traveldoc.aero